# Class 'x' has no 'y' member

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I've been trying to use variables of another method, that belongs to the same class, for compare it.

My code looks like this:

```
def __init__ (self, Title, Complexity, Time):
    self.Title = Title                       
    self.Complexity = Complexity
    self.Time = Time 

def organizatingTime(self):
    if Activitie.Complexity() > 6:
        time = Activitie.Time()
```

but VS shows me

```
Class 'Activitie' has no 'Time' member
Class 'Activitie' has no 'Complexity' member
```

Anything that ***works*** is good.

Comment: Update the question to include the full error traceback.

Comment: You probably want `self.Time` instead of `Activitie.Time`.  Time is an _instance_ attribute, not a _class_ attribute.

Comment: It would help if you included a [mre] - i.e. you're missing the class definition, and it would be easier for everyone to understand an error message from Python instead of a linter warning from VS. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for more advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   def __init__ (self, Title, Complexity, Time):
        self.Title = Title                       
        self.Complexity = Complexity
        self.Time = Time 

    def organizatingTime(self):
        if self.Complexity() > 6:
            time = self.Time()
```